# Log in to Google Maps with my private (non-administered) account

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, google-maps

This has been driving me crazy every couple of weeks for months now...

I have two primary google accounts. One is my private account, the other is the corporate administered account. We'll call the first A and the second B.

I am (usually) able to work comfortably with both accounts open in Chrome, e.g. one tab for gmail A, one for gmail B. So far so good. Chrome is synced to A

Then, I'll open a tab for Google Maps. I am not signed in to the app at this point. I click sign in, and am presented with the login screen for B. I click sign in as a different user, and get a very incorrect (from my perspective) response, telling me that "You are trying to access Google Admin of {B}.com but you do not have a valid logged in account for it."
[image: Not what I'm trying to do at all!] (Sorry for the bookmark tooltip...)

So, without logging out of account B, I don't seem able to log into Maps with account A.

This experience is a lot like biting into a pebble in a bowl of pasta.

Comment: a) I think this is likely off-topic, but b) Google will accept whichever login you last used; to swap for any given tab, you have to swap accounts. It's so bitingly irritating [presumably cookie-based] that you can never win. I had 2 personal accounts [tg not one for work] that got so annoying I had to dump one to regain my sanity. I wish you luck, whilst not actually holding much hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is one of the few reasons I do use Chrome on the desktop!

Chrome supports persona's so simply create a second persona and associate it with the other account. Now you can be logged into both accounts at the same time and still keep them separate. To switch, open a new window and click on the small rectangle in the top-right of the window with your name in it.

It is Microsoft I have this problem with since I have around 5 or 6 different accounts with them for different purposes.

For other browsers, you need to use a new Private Window but then you have to log in each time - Chrome keeps your Google accounts for you. The use of something like LastPass gets round the login issue by putting all of your logins just a couple of clicks away.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a few such accounts, one possible solution is to use different browsers, that way they will each keep their context/cookies related to the right account. E.g. Firefox for work and chrome for private or the contrary.